# Gas laws, finding pressure

Tags: gas-laws

What is the resultant pressure if 0.6 mol of
ideal gas at 273 K and 1.18 atm in a closed
container of constant volume is heated to
563 K?
Answer in units of atm

Answer (score 1):

We have PV=nRT
(where symbols have there usual meaning.)

You see V is constant as the container doesn't change or deform ( as you mentioned)

so thinking that way PV/nRT=constant
as moles are constant and not leaking
R is universal gas constant .
so ;

P/T is constant 
then $P_1/ P_2 = T_1/T_2$

Comment: What about the moles though?

Comment: they would just be constant provided there's no leakage

Comment: Oh I see. So would you just plug it in to be: 1.18/273 = P2/563

Comment: So would it be 2.43?

Comment: hmm; just math , just calculation :)

Comment: Hello and welcome to Chemistry.SE! At this point I suggest you do a couple things. First, take the short [tour] to familiarize yourself with how this site works. Secondly, this is not a "homework" site. You will need to show some work and effort to start off with before others will put their efforts into helping you. How far can you get? What specifically don't you understand? [This](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/141/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-chemistry-stack-exchange/142#142) post give some good guidance for asking homework questions. Best of luck with it!

Comment: yes I knew that should be a comment but didn't had any option ; sorry for that

Comment: @ airhuff I have edited the answer accordingly